# What's the advantage of installing applications using domain accounts ?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to figure out the advantage of installing an application using a Windows 2008 AD account (or disadvantage) over using a local OS account.

Except of security considerations, why would you want to install an app using domain account ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Centralized user provisioning
2. Centralized user de-provisioning
3. Ability to enforce policy on the accounts
4. Centralized auditing of authentication attempts
5. etc.
6. etc.
7. etc.

The main question is: why would you *not* want to use AD accounts for this.